# How to get first N elements of a list in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to use Linq to query a bus schedule in my project, so that at any time I can get the next 5 bus arrival times. How can I limit my query to the first 5 results?

More generally, how can I take a slice of a list in C#? (In Python I would use `mylist[:5]` to get the first 5 elements.)

Answer (score 958, accepted):

```
var firstFiveItems = myList.Take(5);
```

Or to slice:

```
var secondFiveItems = myList.Skip(5).Take(5);
```

And of course often it's convenient to get the first five items according to some kind of order:

```
var firstFiveArrivals = myList.OrderBy(i => i.ArrivalTime).Take(5);
```

Comment: Does it throw exception if there are only, for example, 3 items in the list? Or will it take as many as there are up to 5?

Comment: @bobek : It does not throw an exception. It simply returns what it has if there aren't enough elements.

Comment: exactly, no exceptions thrown Skip and Take combined solved my problem as I wanted take any generic collection and process x items per batch

Comment: It should be noted that `.Take(n)` returns a TakeIterator; it does not return a list with `n` elements in it (assuming that that many are available).  Use `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` on the result of the `Take` to get a concrete array or list.

Comment: Also, it looks like ATM you actually *need* to always use OrderBy. This is what EntityFramework told me in the exception message without it: `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.` I'm assuming it's the same for 'Take', but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 82):

In case anyone is interested (even if the question does not ask for this version), in C# 2 would be: (I have edited the answer, following some suggestions)

```
myList.Sort(CLASS_FOR_COMPARER);
List<string> fiveElements = myList.GetRange(0, 5);
```

Comment: Maybe add an anonymous predicate as well?

Comment: List<T>.Sort returns void; you would need to sort, then use GetRange separately. You could also use a Comparison<T> anonymous method to remove the need for CLASS_FOR_COMPARER.

Comment: @AlexeyMK - you mean a Comparison<T>, not a predicate (Predicate<T>) - a predicate is used to filter data

Comment: I believe this answer is useful even now, 10 years and many C# versions later. For the specific case where you have a list. Especially if you are skipping many items. E.g. you have a list of one million items, and you want a slice of 5 of them, far into the list. GetRange knows exactly where to go to grab them. I don't know whether `Skip` + `Take` is as smart, or whether it enumerates over the skipped items. And I don't need to know -- I just use GetRange (when given a List). Just make sure you realize second parameter is *count* (rather than *last index*).

Comment: The nice thing about `.Take(n)` is that you don't have to worry if there are less than `n` elements in the sequence it works on.  The problem with `List<T>.GetRange(0, count)` is that you do have to worry.... you will get an `ArgumentException` if there aren't `count` items.

Answer (score 10):

Like `pagination` you can use below formule for taking `slice of list or elements`:

```
var slice = myList.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                  .Take(pageSize);
```

Example 1: first five items

```
var pageNumber = 1;
var pageSize = 5;
```

Example 2: second five items

```
var pageNumber = 2;
var pageSize = 5;
```

Example 3: third five items

```
var pageNumber = 3;
var pageSize = 5;
```

> If notice to formule parameters `pageSize = 5` and `pageNumber` is changing, if you want to change number of items in slicing you change `pageSize`.

Answer (score 6):

Working example:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestListLinqTake()
    {
        List<string> elements = new List<string>() { "storm", "earth", "fire"};
        List<string> noErrorThrown = elements.Take(5).ToList();
        List<string> someElements = elements.Take(2).ToList();

        Assert.True(
            someElements.First().Equals("storm") &&
            someElements.Count == 2 &&
            noErrorThrown.Count == 3);
    }
```

Don't forget

```
using System.Linq;
```

Based on Bellarmine Head's comment

Answer (score 3):

To take first 5 elements better use expression like this one:

`var firstFiveArrivals = myList.Where([EXPRESSION]).Take(5);`

or

`var firstFiveArrivals = myList.Where([EXPRESSION]).Take(5).OrderBy([ORDER EXPR]);`

It will be faster than orderBy variant, because LINQ engine will not scan trough all list due to delayed execution, and will not sort all array.

```
class MyList : IEnumerable<int>
{

    int maxCount = 0;

    public int RequestCount
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public MyList(int maxCount)
    {
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        RequestCount = 0;
    }
    #region IEnumerable<int> Members

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < maxCount)
        {
            RequestCount++;
            yield return i++;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new MyList(15);
        list.Take(5).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(list.RequestCount); // 5;

        list.Reset();
        list.OrderBy(q => q).Take(5).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(list.RequestCount); // 15;

        list.Reset();
        list.Where(q => (q & 1) == 0).Take(5).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(list.RequestCount); // 9; (first 5 odd)

        list.Reset();
        list.Where(q => (q & 1) == 0).Take(5).OrderBy(q => q).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(list.RequestCount); // 9; (first 5 odd)
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that you're now ordering only the first 5 elements after you've selected them. It may be faster, but it also has different semantics, which are less likely to be what people actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = (from S in EE.Stagaire
                                    join F in EE.Filiere on
                                    S.IdFiliere equals F.IdFiliere
                                    where S.Nom.StartsWith("A")
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ID=S.Id,
                                        Name = S.Nom,
                                        Prénon= S.Prenon,
                                        Email=S.Email,
                                        MoteDePass=S.MoteDePass,
                                        Filiere = F.Filiere1
                                    }).Take(1).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Mouad, thank you for your answer. While your code might solve the problem in the posted question, good answers explain *why* your solution works. Please consider updating your question.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the **correct answer**, relevant to c# versions starting from 8.0:

**Yes!** It allows us to work exactly the same as in Python.

From c# 8.0 docs:

[C# 8.0 feature specifications:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

This feature is about delivering two new operators that allow constructing System.Index and System.Range objects, and using them to index/slice collections at runtime.

C# refer to the dot chars (..) as the range operator

Examples:

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var slice1 = array[2..^3];    // array[new Range(2, new Index(3, fromEnd: true))]
var slice2 = array[..^3];     // array[Range.EndAt(new Index(3, fromEnd: true))]
var slice3 = array[2..];      // array[Range.StartAt(2)]
var slice4 = array[..];       // array[Range.All]
```