# How can select first 3 item of list<>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using this code for get all news:

```
List<aspnet_News> allNews = context.aspnet_News.OrderByDescending(i => i.NewsId).ToList();
```

How I can select first 3 items of this list and bind into a Datalist, please help, thanks...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) method

```
List<aspnet_News> allNews = context.aspnet_News.OrderByDescending(i => i.NewsId)
                                               .Take(3)  // Takes the first 3 items
                                               .ToList();
```

It'll also handle the case where the list contains less than 3 items and take them only.

Answer (score 2):

Use method Take() and if you need, you can use Skip() as well.

[How to get first N elements of a list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319973/how-to-get-first-n-elements-of-a-list-in-c)