# Get Specific number from List

Tags: c#, list

I have this list `List<string> Url = new List<string>();` with more element >10 and i need to get only 5 element.

I tried in this mode i get all element:

```
foreach (string key3 in Url)
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(key3);
            }
```

Comment: This way you add all the elements in Url to listBox3

Comment: Your question is: ...only 5th element, or first 5 elements?

Comment: Look at this answer on stackoverflow for first N elements in list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319973/how-to-get-first-n-elements-of-a-list-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
{
  listBox3.Items.Add(Url[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
IEnumerable<string> firstFiveUrls = Url.Take(5);
```

[`Enumerable.Take` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

So you could do:

```
// ObjectCollection.AddRange expects an array 
listBox3.Items.AddRange(Url.Take(5).ToArray());
```

[`ObjectCollection.AddRange` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az.aspx)

Comment: another list?? nah thanks =(

Comment: @Federal09 - See update, you're adding to a listbox's items which expects an array

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(Url[i]);
}
```

If you can ensure that there are always > 5 elements, this should be ok.

Comment: It is worth noting that with this approach you should validate the input to ensure it has at least 5 elements before looping

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx)

```
Url.GetRange(0,5);

listBox3.Items.AddRange(Url.GetRange(0,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

With Start index and count..

```
List<string> fiveURLs = URL.GetRange(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

first five elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < Url.Count && i < 5; i++)
    {
         listBox3.Items.Add(Url[i]);
    }
```

fifth element

```
listBox3.Items.Add(Url[4]);
```