# How do I return a list of the three lowest values in another list

Tags: c#, list

How do I return a list of the 3 lowest values in another list. For example, I want to get the 3 lowest values like this:

```
in_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
```

To this:

```
out_list: [2, 3, n, n, n, 1]
```

Maybe a function like this:

```
out_list = function(in_list, 3)?
```

in_list and ouput list is declared like this:

```
List<string> in_list = new List<string>();
List<string> out_list = new List<string>();
```

Can you help me developing a C# code for this? Further explanation can be given.

Comment: What is `[2, 3, n, n, n, 1]`, especially the `n`?

Comment: Since you have `List<String>`, not `List<int>` what is the comparsion rule? E.g.if `"10" > "9"` or (lexicographical) `"10" < "9"`?

Comment: The n value is a flag that tells you that the input value in i'th position isn't one of the 3 loewst value. The output needs to have this flag on.

Comment: You can see the [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319973/how-to-get-first-n-elements-of-a-list-in-c)

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko, I would make a Convert.ToDouble for each value and compare them with each other

Comment: What is the *duplicates policy*? e.g. if you have, say `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]`?

Comment: Hi Bon, I don't want to reorder the output list so it will be like above and I want only to have values if they are one of the 3 lowest values on the in_list

Comment: where do the values come from? what do you expect if the list looks like this: `[a, b, 2, value, test, 5]`

Comment: If I have duplicates it's still the 3 lowest. If lets say in_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] , out_list = [1, 1, 1, n, n, n, n]

Comment: My in_list string has always double values or empty spaces converted to String(), won't be like you've said Fanax

Comment: A sample of values in in_list:
["0,0119861008081834", 
"0,0219810252606099",
"0,0140163198375827",
"0,0479834459063756"]

Comment: With my sample the out_list would be like this:

["0,0119861008081834",
"0,0219810252606099",
"0,0140163198375827",
"n"]

Comment: @user3664117 you should specify all of this first in your question. answers really matter on information you give. im just saying so next time you want to ask question make sure to put all needed information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want those weird `n`, there's this simple solution:

```
public static List<string> Function(List<string> inputList, int max)
{
    var inputIntegers = inputList
        .Select(z => int.Parse(z))
        .ToList();

    var maxAuthorizedValue = inputIntegers
        .OrderBy(z => z)
        .Take(max)
        .Last();

    return inputIntegers
        .Select(z => z <= maxAuthorizedValue ? z.ToString() : "n")
        .ToList();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> in_list = new List<string> { "2", "3", "4", "6", "1", "7" };

    var res = Function(in_list, 3);

    Console.Read();
}
```

---

For your new requirement about duplicates, you could limit the max number of integer your return:

```
public static List<string> Function(List<string> inputList, int max)
{
    var inputIntegers = inputList.Select(z => int.Parse(z)).ToList();

    var maxAuthorizedValue = inputIntegers
        .OrderBy(z => z)
        .Take(max)
        .Last();

    // I don't really like that kind of LINQ query (which modifies some variable
    // inside the Select projection), so a good old for loop would probably
    // be more appropriated
    int returnedItems = 0;
    return inputIntegers.Select(z =>
        {
            return (z <= maxAuthorizedValue && ++returnedItems <= max) ? z.ToString() : "n";
        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This assumes all input values are different.

Comment: I don't think this will work where you have 2 authorized values of a higher value than another authorized value later in the List - e.g. `[2, 2, 2, 1, 6, 1]` will give `[2,2,2,n,n,n]` instead of `[2,n,n,1,n,1]`

Comment: The only problem here is that the values are double and not int. How can I try to Parse with double?

Comment: I'll try this solution by making a modification like replacing in.Parse to double.Pars :)

Comment: I've tried this with my changes and got what i needed, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You need two queries, one to determine the lowest items and one to fill the result-list. You can use a `HashSet` for faster loookups:

```
var lowest = new HashSet<String>(in_list
    .Select(s => new { s, val = int.Parse(s) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.val)
    .Take(3)
    .Select(x => x.s));
List<string> out_list = in_list.Select(s => lowest.Contains(s) ? s : "n").ToList();
```

---

If you actually only want 3 and duplicates are possible this is the best i've come up with:

```
var lowest = new HashSet<String>(in_list
    .Select(s => new { s, val = int.Parse(s) })
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x.val)
    .Take(3)
    .Select(x => x.s));
List<string> out_list = in_list
    .Select((str, index) => new { str, index, value = int.Parse(str) })
    .GroupBy(x => x.str)
    .SelectMany(g => lowest.Contains(g.Key) 
        ?  g.Take(1).Concat(g.Skip(1).Select(x => new { str = "n", x.index, x.value }))
        :  g.Select(x => new { str = "n", x.index, x.value }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.index)
    .Select(x => x.str)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: in case `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]` the lowest 4 are shown instead of the lowest 3

Comment: @fubo: yes, that is intended. If you read his comment it seems that he wants this behaviour: _"The n value is a flag that tells you that the input value in i'th position isn't one of the 3 lowest value. The output needs to have this flag on"_ My understanding is that he wants to know whether an item is part of the `top n` items or not. It also not clear if duplicates are possible at all.

Comment: @fubo: would be nice to know it beforehand

Comment: @fubo: i've provided another way which takes it into account but i'm not happy with it. It's far too complicated and also not very efficient.

Comment: Won't this return `n` for all but the first of any duplicate? e.g. the `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]` that @fubo mentioned would return `[1, n, 2, n, n, n, n]` rather than `[1, 1, 2, n, n, n, n]`?

Comment: @petelids: yes, still not correct? At least this is another unclear part of the question. I thought from the comments that he wants to find the TOP3 numbers and in case of duplicates to show only  the first. But one comment of OP makes me wonder if my asssumption was correct: _"[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] , out_list = [1, 1, 1, n, n, n, n]"_ My approach would return [1, n, n, n, n, n, n]. However, OP accepted another answer so i keep this in case he'll change his mind.

Comment: Yep, I was going on the comment you've mentioned (which is why I ended up using aggregate in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33347284/3791802)). It seems from the accepted answer that my understanding is perhaps wrong as I don't think it will give the answer the OP wants as per my comment on that question. Anyway, +1 for your solution as it _does_ work the way you intended it to!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Aggregate` to grab a `Dictionary` of each element with its corresponding number of allowed occurrences which you could then use to grab your values from the input list:

```
public static List<string> GetList(List<string> in_list, int max)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> occurrences = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    int itemsAdded = 0;

    in_list.OrderBy(x => x).Aggregate(occurrences, (list, aggr) =>
    {
        if (itemsAdded++ < max)
        {
            if (occurrences.ContainsKey(aggr))
                occurrences[aggr]++;
            else
                occurrences.Add(aggr, 1);
        }

        return list;
    });

    //occurrences now contains only each required elements 
    //with the number of occurrences allowed of that element

    List<string> out_list = in_list.Select(x =>
    {
        return (occurrences.ContainsKey(x) && occurrences[x]-- > 0 ? x : "n");
    }).ToList();

    return out_list;
}
```