# When using Take(...) on a List<T>, is the entire list returned before Take(...) is applied?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, optimization

I have a `List` of elements of type

```
    public class FriendList 
    {
        public List<string> friends { get; set; } // List of friends names
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; } // date/time on the data file
    }
```

and I need a procedure that gets the top 2 ordered by `timestamp` (and then does some other stuff with them). So what I started writing is

```
    public void CompareLastTwo ( )
    {
        if ( this._fhist.Count < 2 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Need at least two instances of Facebook profile data in the Data folder");
        }

        FriendList latest, secondLatest; 
        if ( this._fhist[0].timestamp > this._fhist[1].timestamp )
        {
            latest = this._fhist[0];
            secondLatest = this._fhist[1];
        }
        else
        {
            latest = this._fhist[1];
            secondLatest = this._fhist[0];
        }

        for ( int i = 2, n = this._fhist.Count; i < n; ++i )
        {
            if ( this._fhist[i].timestamp > latest.timestamp )
            {
                secondLatest = latest;
                latest = this._fhist[i];
            }
            else if ( this._fhist[i].timestamp > secondLatest.timestamp && this._fhist[i].timestamp <= latest.timestamp )
            {
                secondLatest = this._fhist[i];
            }
        }

        // ... 

    }
```

but then I realized from looking at [How to get first N elements of a list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319973/how-to-get-first-n-elements-of-a-list-in-c) that I can do

```
List<FriendList> latestTwoFriendLists = this._fhist.OrderBy(L => L.timestamp).Take(2);
```

which is more compact, but ***is it as efficient***???? Or does the process of computing the right side of the equation get an entire ordered list before `Take`ing first 2?

Comment: Well, logically, the ordering *must* be done first if you want the first two to be the 'lowest' two items.

Comment: @Rob No, you can find the two lowest with a single iteration through the collection, like I did

Comment: Well, yes, but you're still iterating the entire collection, which is what `OrderBy` does as well. The `OrderBy.Take` is lazily executed, so while `OrderBy` does iterate the entire collection, it doesn't create a new ordered list.

Comment: @Rob I would assume that `OrderBy` quicksorts the collection, which means it does more than just iterate over the collection once

Comment: @Rob regular sorting which is done by `OrderBy` is always O(n * log(n)), picking "top-k" (where k is fixed and not depending on n) is O(n) - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Selection_algorithms - like QuickSelect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OrderBy` will sort the entire collection when `Take` requests first item.

So the entire LINQ query will be *O(n*log(n))*, not *O(n)* like your existing code.

Comment: Yes, but in this case it would be better to use more compact and obvious piece of code until it becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: It doesn't sort the collection before returning an iterator.  It does nothing but null check the arguments before returning an iterator.  It *does* need to sort the entire collection when asking for the first item though.  It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, OrderBy does not have to sort all items in this case, if it is implemented as lazy sort. Standard linq sort is not lazy so it will sort everything. Your solution is as fast as it can be, You would not find better. Just make it standalone function to clean things up, like this:

```
 public class FriendList
        {
            public List<string> friends { get; set; } // List of friends names
            public DateTime timestamp { get; set; } // date/time on the data file
        }

        public static Tuple<T, T> GetTwoBiggest<T>(IEnumerable<T> array, Comparison<T> comp)
        {
            var enumerator = array.GetEnumerator();

            if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) { throw new ArgumentException("We need collection with at least two items"); }
            T max1 = enumerator.Current;

            if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) { throw new ArgumentException("We need collection with at least two items"); }
            T max2 = enumerator.Current;

            if (comp(max1, max2) < 0)
            {
                T tmp = max1;
                max1 = max2;
                max2 = tmp;
            }

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                T actual = enumerator.Current;
                if (comp(actual, max1) > 0)
                {
                    max2 = max1;
                    max1 = actual;
                }
                else if (comp(actual, max2) > 0)
                {
                    max2 = actual;
                }
            }

            return new Tuple<T, T>(max1, max2);
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<FriendList> list = new List<FriendList>()
            {
                new FriendList() { timestamp = new DateTime(2015,1,1) },
                new FriendList() { timestamp = new DateTime(2015,10,2) },
                new FriendList() { timestamp = new DateTime(2015,5,3) },
                new FriendList() { timestamp = new DateTime(2015,2,4) },
                new FriendList() { timestamp = new DateTime(2015,3,5) },
                new FriendList() { timestamp = new DateTime(2015,7,6) },
                new FriendList() { timestamp = new DateTime(2015,11,7) },
                new FriendList() { timestamp = new DateTime(2015,8,8) },
            };

            var twoBiggest = GetTwoBiggest(list, (a, b) => a.timestamp.CompareTo(b.timestamp));

            Console.WriteLine(twoBiggest.Item1.timestamp);
            Console.WriteLine(twoBiggest.Item2.timestamp);
        }
```