# Limit datagrid items in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am using `DataGrid` in ASP.NET C# . I want to limit and control the **number of items displayed** in a `DataGrid` (I am forced to use this controller).

I know we can control using

1. `AllowPaging = "TRUE"` per page basis
2. Limit `DataSource` using `sql` query and then binding (`DataBind()`) it.

But I don't want either. I want to run `sql` query once and get all data, then I must be able to display first 10 or 20 items depending on the requirements.

It's preferable if I could do it

1. in code behind.
2. without page reload, if I increase the item size to 30 from 10

Any kind of heads up in right path appreciated

Comment: Are you allowed to use ajax?

Comment: If you are using `JQuery` in your project. This link may be helpful to you : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Infinite-Scroll-Endless-Scroll-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options to consider. The first uses a `DataTable` and `Linq` to get the top x rows.

```
DataTable dt = yourDataTableSource;
GridView1.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(5).CopyToDataTable();
//Linq example with sorting added
//GridView1.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x["columnName"]).Take(5).CopyToDataTable();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Or you could use the same attributes that are normally found on the .aspx page. Only these are set in code behind now and you can still use your current datasource for that.

```
GridView1.PageSize = 5;
GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

or for a DataGrid

```
DataGrid1.PageSize = 10;
DataGrid1.AllowPaging = true;
DataGrid1.PagerStyle.Visible = false;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

And to complete your question, here is a little example to get you started of how get the change in the items displayed without a page refresh.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <!-- a ScriptManager is required when working with UpdatePanels -->

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="5 rows" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10 rows" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="15 rows" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = yourDataTableSource;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.PageSize = 10;
            GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
            GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            ViewState["GridView1Content"] = dt;
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pageSize = 10;

        //always do validation with user input...
        try
        {
            pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        GridView1.PageSize = pageSize;
        GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["GridView1Content"] as DataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: i'm giving u +1 but, I explicitly mentioned, I am forced to use Datagrid, not GridView. Even though they are similar in some aspect, they have different features. And I've already mentioned I don't want paging

Comment: You can use both options I mentioned with a DataGrid also. And by settings `DataGrid1.PagerStyle.Visible = false;` (instead of `GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;` for GrideViews) there is no paging visible to the user.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful, but in your example, you are binding the datasurce depending on the size, when the size increases, it's slow. I think if appending the next set without binding all would be a better solution. How can I append values to `DataGrid`

Comment: Then you have to get the data from the database and bind that. I know you stated that you dont want to hit the databse twice, but you also don't want all the data in a set because it would get too big and slow... So where should the data come from then?

Comment: I want to send a db request and get all the required data once. Then I should show them in 10, 20, .... What I want is to build first 10 rows, then next 10 rows and so on. I DON'T WANT TO BUILD FIRST 20 ROWS.

Comment: That is exactly what my example does. It stores the data into a viewstate: `ViewState["GridView1Content"]` and it adds the rows when the DropDown is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I came something like this but i was using gridview and when page come too loaded o migrated to Datatables with serverside page processing.

It´s a generic layer. Modify it to ur need!

Here´s the parser i got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;

namespace iMax_WeSite.app.Objects.DataTables
{
    public class DataTable
    {
        public DataTable()
        {
        }
        public int sEcho { get; set; }
        public int iTotalRecords { get; set; }
        public int iTotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }
        public string iTotalValue { get; set; } //Somatoria total do valor
        public string iTotalFilteredValue { get; set; } //Somatoria parcial do valor
        public List<List<string>> aaData { get; set; }
        public string sColumns { get; set; }

        public void Import(string[] properties)
        {
            sColumns = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
            {
                sColumns += properties[i];
                if (i < properties.Length - 1)
                    sColumns += ",";
            }
        }
    }
    public class DataTableParser<T>
    {
        private const string INDIVIDUAL_SEARCH_KEY_PREFIX = "sSearch_";
        private const string INDIVIDUAL_SORT_KEY_PREFIX = "iSortCol_";
        private const string INDIVIDUAL_SORT_DIRECTION_KEY_PREFIX = "sSortDir_";
        private const string DISPLAY_START = "iDisplayStart";
        private const string DISPLAY_LENGTH = "iDisplayLength";
        private const string ECHO = "sEcho";
        private const string SEARCH = "sSearch";
        private const string ASCENDING_SORT = "asc";
        private IQueryable<T> _queriable;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _tableParams;
        private readonly Type _type;
        private readonly System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] _properties;
        public DataTableParser(Dictionary<string, object> tableParams, IQueryable<T> queriable)
        {
            _queriable = queriable;
            _tableParams = tableParams;
            _type = typeof(T);
            _properties = _type.GetProperties();
        }

        public DataTable Parse()
        {
            var list = new DataTable();
            list.Import(_properties.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());

            list.sEcho = (int)_tableParams[ECHO];

            list.iTotalRecords = _queriable.Count();

            ApplySort();

            int skip = 0, take = list.iTotalRecords;
            if (_tableParams.ContainsKey(DISPLAY_START))
                skip = (int)_tableParams[DISPLAY_START];
            if (_tableParams.ContainsKey(DISPLAY_LENGTH))
                take = (int)_tableParams[DISPLAY_LENGTH];

            //tenho de segregar para mostrar o filtrado 
            list.aaData = _queriable.Where(ApplyGenericSearch)
                                    .Where(IndividualPropertySearch)
                                    .Skip(skip)
                                    .Take(take)
                                    .Select(SelectProperties)
                                    .ToList();

            //tenho de segregar para mostrar o filtrado geral
            list.iTotalDisplayRecords = _queriable.Where(ApplyGenericSearch)
                                                    .Where(IndividualPropertySearch)
                                                    .Select(SelectProperties)
                                                    .Count();
            return list;
        }
        private void ApplySort()
        {
            foreach (string key in _tableParams.Keys.Where(x => x.StartsWith(INDIVIDUAL_SORT_KEY_PREFIX)))
            {
                int sortcolumn = (int)_tableParams[key];
                if (sortcolumn < 0 || sortcolumn >= _properties.Length)
                    break;

                string sortdir = _tableParams[INDIVIDUAL_SORT_DIRECTION_KEY_PREFIX + key.Replace(INDIVIDUAL_SORT_KEY_PREFIX, string.Empty)].ToString();

                var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "val");
                var propertyExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(paramExpr, _properties[sortcolumn]), typeof(object)), paramExpr);


                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortdir) || sortdir.Equals(ASCENDING_SORT, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    _queriable = _queriable.OrderBy(propertyExpr);
                else
                    _queriable = _queriable.OrderByDescending(propertyExpr);
            }
        }

        private Expression<Func<T, List<string>>> SelectProperties
        {
            get
            {
                return value => _properties.Select
                                            (
                                                prop => (prop.GetValue(value, new object[0]) ?? string.Empty).ToString()
                                            )
                                            .ToList();
            }
        }

        private Expression<Func<T, bool>> IndividualPropertySearch
        {
            get
            {
                var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "val");
                Expression whereExpr = Expression.Constant(true); // default is val => True
                foreach (string key in _tableParams.Keys.Where(x => x.StartsWith(INDIVIDUAL_SEARCH_KEY_PREFIX)))
                {
                    int property = -1;

                    if (!int.TryParse(key.Replace(INDIVIDUAL_SEARCH_KEY_PREFIX, string.Empty), out property) || property >= _properties.Length || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_tableParams[key].ToString())) 
                        continue; // ignore if the option is invalid

                    string query = _tableParams[key].ToString().ToLower();

                    var toStringCall = Expression.Call(
                                        Expression.Call(
                                            Expression.Property(paramExpr, _properties[property]), "ToString", new Type[0]),
                                                                typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[0]));

                    whereExpr = Expression.And(whereExpr,
                                                Expression.Call(toStringCall,
                                                                typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase),
                                                                Expression.Constant(query)));

                }
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(whereExpr, paramExpr);
            }
        }

        private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ApplyGenericSearch
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_tableParams.ContainsKey(SEARCH) || _properties.Length == 0)
                    return x => true;

                string search = _tableParams[SEARCH].ToString();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                    return x => true;

                var searchExpression = Expression.Constant(search.ToLower());
                var paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "val");

                var propertyQuery = (from property in _properties
                                        let tostringcall = Expression.Call(
                                                            Expression.Call(
                                                                Expression.Property(paramExpression, property), "ToString", new Type[0]),
                                                                typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[0]))
                                        select Expression.Call(tostringcall, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), searchExpression)).ToArray();

                Expression compoundExpression = propertyQuery[0];

                for (int i = 1; i < propertyQuery.Length; i++)
                    compoundExpression = Expression.Or(compoundExpression, propertyQuery[i]);

                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(compoundExpression, paramExpression);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I hope i´ve helped in your problem!

Answer (score 1):

However, we have to add a `list` (could be any kind of list) to `datasource` when we are using `DataGrid` control.

All what we want to do is, limit the number of items in this `list` and then bind your data using `DataBind()`.

[To limit number of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319976/3966458)

```
var firstFiveItems = myList.Take(5);
```

or

```
var secondFiveItems = myList.Skip(5).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you  tried Datatable Plugin It has functionality to display record as per our requirement..
 See this [link](https://datatables.net/)

Apply Datatable Plugin For Your Grid To display data and you can change this option by Changing `aLengthMenu` and `iDisplayLength` properties as per your requirement.. this is in built functionality

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, -1], [10, 20, 30, "All"]],// set as per your requirement
        "iDisplayLength": 10 // dont forget to change as per alengthmenu


    });
} );
```