# Assigning objects from another list to another group of lists

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of something.

```
public List<Objects> obj;
```

The objects in this list need to be added to these other lists.

```
public List<Objects> objGroup1, objGroup2, objGroup3, objGroup4;
```

I assign them right now by doing this.

```
void AssignToGroups()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.Count ; i++)
    {
//Need the first 4 for group 1 next 4 for group 2 and so on...

        if(i < 4)
        {
            objGroup1.Add(obj[i]);
        }

        else if(i >= 4 && i < 8)
        {
            objGroup2.Add(obj[i]);
        }

        else if (i >= 8 && i < 12)
        {
            objGroup3.Add(obj[i]);
        }

        else if (i >= 12 && i < 16)
        {
            objGroup4.Add(obj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm planning on expanding and my method for grouping objects right now will fill my screen with endless if and else statements.

4 objects need to be assigned to each groups.
The objects in the group gets them in their order of arrangement.
e.g. group1 gets obj 1-4. group 2 get obj 5-8 and so on...

Does anyone have a better method of grouping objects like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

You'll need the `using System.Linq;`:

```
objGroup1 = obj.Take(4).ToList();           //edited: use ToList() to keep the list format
objGroup2 = obj.Skip(4).Take(4).ToList();
objGroup3 = obj.Skip(8).Take(4).ToList();    
objGroup4 = obj.Skip(12).Take(4).ToList();
objGroup5 = obj.Skip(16).Take(4).ToList();
```

Let me know if it works, since I am not able to test it now, except for the syntax.

You can also group the `obj` before `Take()`, such as

```
var orderedobj = obj.OrderBy(i => "some order criteria").ToList();
objGroup1 = orderedobj.Take(4);
...
```

I referenced my answer on [How to get first N elements of a list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319973/how-to-get-first-n-elements-of-a-list-in-c).

EDIT:

In case you *somehow* do not want to use Linq, you can also use [GetRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
objGroup1 = obj.GetRange(0, 4);
objGroup2 = obj.GetRange(3, 4);     //since GetRange(index, count) has index starting from 0 instead of 1
objGroup3 = obj.GetRange(7, 4);     //count stays the same since we always want 4 elements
objGroup4 = obj.GetRange(11, 4);
objGroup5 = obj.GetRange(15, 4);
```

Comment: Am having convertion problems.

Comment: Ah, I saw the comment (disappeared now) asking for an answer without Linq so I added some edit to my answer. Anyways, could you specify what kind of conversion error you see?

Comment: I think I know the problem, it just needed a ToList() at the end.

Comment: Yeah the edit button disappeared for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Keyur's excellent answer, you could create a method that will create the groups for you, based on any source list, with a configurable group size:

```
private static List<List<object>> AssignToGroups(List<object> source, int groupSize)
{
    var groups = new List<List<object>>();

    if (source == null || groupSize < 1) return groups;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count / groupSize; i++)
    {
        groups.Add(source.Skip(groupSize * i).Take(groupSize).ToList());
    }

    return groups;
}
```

**Usage**

```
private static void Main()
{
    var mainList = new List<object>
    {
        "one", "two", "three", "four","five",
        "six","seven","eight","nine","ten",
        "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen","fifteen",
        "sixteen","seventeen","eightteen","nineteen","twenty",
        "twentyone", "twentytwo", "twentythree", "twentyfour","twentyfive",
        "twentysix","twentyseven","twentyeight","twentynine","thirty",
        "thirtyone", "thirtytwo", "thirtythree", "thirtyfour","thirtyfive",
        "thirtysix","thirtyseven","thirtyeight","thirtynine","forty",
    };

    var groups = AssignToGroups(mainList, 4);

    for (var i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Group #{i + 1}: {string.Join(", ", groups[i])}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]