# Limit items List c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, items

How to do that from List ids in which 10 items in List cids, came in turn on 2 items?

```
internal List<items> test(List<long> ids)
{
    //ids = 10 items  
    List<long> cids = new List<long>(); // max 2 items in List<long> ids 

    var result= classA.GetValue(cids); //max cids items 2
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Try: `cids.Take(2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first N elements of a list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319973/how-to-get-first-n-elements-of-a-list-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

Is it really so simply? Use `Take`:

```
 internal List<items> test(List<long> ids)
 {
     return classA.GetValue(ids.Take(2).ToList()).Take(2).ToList();
 }
```

I dont know why you need to take 2 from the ids and pass these to `GetValue` as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq,

`var cids = ids.Take(2).ToList();`

That's probably the simplest. Not much more to add... unless I gravely misunderstood the question.