# How to do Top n on JArray?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JArray as below:

```
_ja_data = new JArray(_ja.OrderBy(obj => (string)obj["km"]));
```

it contains lots of route data of a trip, I did OrderBy "km" but I only want to show 10 data.

How to do Top n on JArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `.Take(N)`  is what you're looking for. Take takes the first N elements into a new list. So try:

```
_ja_data = new JArray(_ja.OrderBy(obj => (string)obj["km"])).Take(10);
```

Credit goes to: [How to get first N elements of a list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319973/how-to-get-first-n-elements-of-a-list-in-c)

Comment: Normally you would flag as _duplicate_ but I see you don't have the rep.... _yet_.  ;)   +1 regardless